# I am getting a 500 internal error whilst creating a simple mvc php app

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a simple MVC based application using php. However when i clean my index.php up and move the code into its own file i get the following error, Internal Server Error 500.

The code is below;

Index.php

```
<php
  require = 'libs/Bootstrap.php';
  $app = new Bootstrap();
?>
```

Bootstrap.php

```
<?php
  class Bootstrap {

   function __construct(){
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $url = rtrim($url, '/');
    $url = explode('/', $url);

    require '../controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php';
    $controller = new $url[0];


    if (isset($url[2])) {
     $controller-> {$url[1]}($url[2]);
    }else {
     if (isset($url[1])) {
      $controller-> {$url[1]}();
    }
   }
 }
}

?>
```

help.php

```
<?php

 class Help {

  function __construct(){
    echo 'We are inside help <br />';
  }

  public function other($arg = false){
   echo "we are inside other <br />";
   echo "Optional :" . $arg . '<br />';
  }
 }

?>
```

Comment: Have you, by any chance, looked at your error logs?

Comment: Where is url from in $_GET['url']

Comment: its the url of the webpage